# Unstable result in jsp while using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am currently working in jsp. I need to get the value of input on text box while a buttton is clicked. My code is given below. While running it produces output which disappears in seconds. I need a stable output (text in textbox) when button is clicked.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         body  {
         background-color: #cccccc;
         }
         tab{ padding-left: 4em; }
      </style>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <form>
      <title>Businesscard Management</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <h2>   Search : <input type="text" class="textbox" size="75" id="myText" autofocus="true" name="searchinput"/></h2>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myText").value="ertyu";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe, your button submit the form, so your page is reloaded. You should block the propagation of the event in your function. have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Why is there a `form` tag under meta tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have some errors in your code markup. You have just one opened `<form>` tag inside of `<head>` tag. Also I noticed that you're trying to set styles for **tab** but this is not appropriate tag. And you forgot to close `</html>` tag. Be careful when writing code, better to use code indention for better reading and it could prevent plenty of errors.

regarding your code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #cccccc;
        }

        tab {
            padding-left: 4em;
        }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Businesscard Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <form action="/">
        <h2> Search : <input type="text" class="textbox" size="75" id="myText" autofocus="true" name="searchinput"/></h2>
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Try it"/>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myText").value = "ertyu";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've move `<form>` tag to it desired position. And replaced `<button>` with `<input type="button">` to prevent form submitting. So regarding your code when you press Try it button you will assign "ertyu" text to the input value. And if you want to get value of it, just use `document.getElementById("myText").value`